# R - How to pass encrypted password in a GET request

Tags: r, rest, encryption

I am pulling data from a server using [this API.](https://nrdata.nps.gov/programs/water/Aquarius/AQUARIUS%203.10%20Publish%20Service%20API%20Manual.pdf) In order to get an authToken I need to pass my username and password. The password input description says "Hashed password. May be passed as clear text, or as RSA-encrypted hash
(see above for RSA public key)."

To encrypt the password I am using the below code.

```
library(openssl)

aqKey <- read_pubkey("public_key.pem")
user_name <- "UserName"
password <- rsa_encrypt(charToRaw(askpass()), aqKey)
pw <- rawToChar(password)
```

This gives me a string with a bunch of unusable characters that produce a 400 error when used in the URL.

```
/GetAuthToken?user=USERNAME&encPwd=ˆ Ù\026Õ©1tÐÆ®IßÊ/ÛÅÆwéÙeµèB¾kz–V\t–ü˜ÞO«~=ñcÑªÿC'p‰-zòjEü,\r¯eÑ}d‹ã\fÀ\030DR·W\026Â\022‰Å:™¶í©«cózÆlE\032Ï4$é¹Þ,ù«…s\021…–ì\026}h¯~?\nC\021ôj-†\032K}ò\026
```

If I use `base64_encode()` or `URLencode()` on either `password` or `pw` I get a 200 status but do not receive a token. This is equivalent to an incorrect password. When I pass the password as plaintext I get a token.

My question is, how should I be formatting the password once it has been encrypted so that the server will recognize it as an encrypted password?